# Column shading, alternative to xcolor package

Tags: tables, color, columns, shading

I want every second column in my table to have a shading for improved readability. I have used the `xcolor` package `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` using the command `\cellcolor[gray]{0.9}`. It works, but it messes with the grid lines and looks absolutely unprofessional. Is there a better way?

Comment: As always on the site you are more likely to get help if you provide something that others can test

Comment: you can look at tikz tables, or I usually recommend not having rules and coloured backgrounds at the same time, do you really need both?

Comment: if it's the whole column why not `\columncolor` rather than `\cellcolor` ? neither in fact should affect the rules in any way although you may see some artefacts at some zoom levels in some viewers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `{NicaTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 4.0 2020-05-08), we have tools to color cells, rows and columns before the rules are drawn. **The rules won't vanish in the PDF viewers at some levels of zoom.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}


\begin{NiceTabular}{C|C|C}%
  [code-before = \columncolor{red!15}{2}]
rosa          & lilium     & tulipa    \\
phaloaenopsis & dianthus   & freesia   \\
alstroemeria  & gladiolus  & narcissus \\
papaver       & helianthus & allium    \\
alyssum       & angelonia  & hibiscus  \\
hydrangea     & saporania  & sedum     \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: In this answer, since version 5.0 of `nicematrix` one must write `c|c|c` instead of `C|C|C` in the preamble of `{NiceTabular}` (but there is an option for backward compatibility).